# MediaWiki API isCategory

Tags: mediawiki, categories, mediawiki-api

I need to know the category of the page.
I've found [mw.Api.plugin.category](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/mw.Api.plugin.category)
, but couldn't make it work. I'm trying to pass the category name as a parameter but im getting the error message that isCategory is not a function.

I tried reading "api" below, to know what are it's methods,etc, and i don't see isCategory on it.

```
var api = new mw.Api();
```

I already used mw.user.getName() from the documentation and it's working.

Can anyone tell me how to use the code, please?
Any exmaples and links would be helpful.

Comment: Category of which page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the category of the current page, you can simply use the [page-specific properties of `mw.config`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/JavaScript#Page-specific):

```
mw.config.get("wgCategories")
```

No need for an api call!